# `gradle run` without gradle

Tags: java, gradle

Within my Java project I am using gradle for dependency management. I have a main class `org.myorg.MainClass` and I can get it to run with `gradle run`.

However when I use `gradle assembly` to generate `jar`, I am unable to get it to run without gradle.

`java -jar assembly.jar` ends immediately with no result.

I even added:

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Class-Path': configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' '),
                'Main-Class': 'org.myorg.MainClass'
        )
    }
}
```

Which helped with the main class file, but that did not help.

I also don't like the fact, that the MainClass is being repeated in different parts of the gradle file - meaning if the MainClass is changed, I will have to replace it on several places.

Comment: Just as a small note, you can simplify `it.getName()` to `it.name` and the whole thing to `configurations.compile*.name.join(' ')`.

Comment: You can use `mainClassName` (from the `application` plugin) in your `jar` task configuration (i.e. `'Main-Class': mainClassName`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main issue is probably that your dependencies aren't been brought in to your executable Jar file and the runtime can't find them when it's time to execute the code. I'm only speculating based on how you formulated your question.

If I'm correct, then I think your best bet right now is to use the Shadow Jar Plugin (https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/introduction/)

> Shadow is a Gradle plugin for combining dependency classes and resources with a project's into a single output Jar. The combined Jar is often referred to a fat-jar or uber-jar. Shadow utilizes JarInputStream and JarOutputStream to efficiently process dependent libraries into the output jar without incurring the I/O overhead of expanding the jars to disk.

Answer (score 0):

Run not the output "jar" but the "fat jar". `java -jar assembly-fat.jar`